# Win32 API fails to CreateWindowW()

Tags: c++, visual-studio, winapi

I am trying to get into WinAPI. I started with the base Win32 Application template in VS. I created a custom dialog `IDD_DIALOG1` and wanted to replace the standard one that comes with the template. However, whenever I launch the application it will terminate almost instantly. My dialog will not display because `CreateWindowW()` fails and `GetLastError()` returns 1407 (ERROR_CANNOT_FIND_WND_CLASS). I have no idea what the issue is, since if I replace the custom dialog with any other resource (such as the auto-generated aboutbox `IDD_ABOUTBOX`) it also launches as expected, opening a window. I found similar threads with the same issue, but none of the solutions there seemed to help me and I have no idea what to do next.

main.cpp:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "Win32Project1.h"

#define MAX_LOADSTRING 100

// Global Variables:
HINSTANCE hInst;                                // current instance
WCHAR szTitle[MAX_LOADSTRING];                  // The title bar text
WCHAR szWindowClass[MAX_LOADSTRING];            // the main window class name

// Forward declarations of functions included in this code module:
ATOM                MyRegisterClass(HINSTANCE hInstance);
BOOL                InitInstance(HINSTANCE, int);
LRESULT CALLBACK    WndProc(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);

int APIENTRY wWinMain(_In_ HINSTANCE hInstance,
    _In_opt_ HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
    _In_ LPWSTR    lpCmdLine,
    _In_ int       nCmdShow)
{
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(hPrevInstance);
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(lpCmdLine);

    // Initialize global strings
    LoadStringW(hInstance, IDS_APP_TITLE, szTitle, MAX_LOADSTRING);
    LoadStringW(hInstance, IDD_DIALOG1, szWindowClass, MAX_LOADSTRING);
    MyRegisterClass(hInstance);

    // Perform application initialization:
    if (!InitInstance(hInstance, nCmdShow))
    {
        return GetLastError();
    }

    MSG msg;

    // Main message loop:
    while (GetMessage(&msg, nullptr, 0, 0))
    {
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }
    return (int)msg.wParam;
}

ATOM MyRegisterClass(HINSTANCE hInstance)
{
    WNDCLASSEXW wcex = {};
    wcex.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);

    wcex.style = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
    wcex.lpfnWndProc = WndProc;
    wcex.cbClsExtra = 0;
    wcex.cbWndExtra = 0;
    wcex.hInstance = hInstance;
    wcex.hIcon = LoadIcon(hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDI_WIN32PROJECT1));
    wcex.hCursor = LoadCursor(nullptr, IDC_ARROW);
    wcex.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)(COLOR_WINDOW + 1);
    wcex.lpszMenuName = NULL;
    wcex.lpszClassName = szWindowClass;
    wcex.hIconSm = LoadIcon(wcex.hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDI_SMALL));

    return RegisterClassExW(&wcex);
}

BOOL InitInstance(HINSTANCE hInstance, int nCmdShow)
{
    hInst = hInstance;

    HWND hWnd = CreateWindowW(szWindowClass, szTitle, WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
        CW_USEDEFAULT, 0, CW_USEDEFAULT, 0, nullptr, nullptr, hInstance, nullptr);
    if (!hWnd)
    {
        return false;
    }

    ShowWindow(hWnd, nCmdShow);
    UpdateWindow(hWnd);

    return true;
}

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (message) {
        case WM_DESTROY: {
            PostQuitMessage(0);
            break;
        }

        case WM_PAINT:
        {
            PAINTSTRUCT ps;
            HDC hdc = BeginPaint(hWnd, &ps);
            EndPaint(hWnd, &ps);
        }
        break;
    }
    return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
}
```

resource.rc:

```
// Microsoft Visual C++ generated resource script.
//
#include "resource.h"

#define APSTUDIO_READONLY_SYMBOLS
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//
// Generated from the TEXTINCLUDE 2 resource.
//
#ifndef APSTUDIO_INVOKED
#include "targetver.h"
#endif
#define APSTUDIO_HIDDEN_SYMBOLS
#include "windows.h"
#undef APSTUDIO_HIDDEN_SYMBOLS

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
#undef APSTUDIO_READONLY_SYMBOLS

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// English (United States) resources

#if !defined(AFX_RESOURCE_DLL) || defined(AFX_TARG_ENU)
LANGUAGE LANG_ENGLISH, SUBLANG_ENGLISH_US

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//
// Icon
//

// Icon with lowest ID value placed first to ensure application icon
// remains consistent on all systems.
IDI_WIN32PROJECT1       ICON                    "Win32Project1.ico"

IDI_SMALL               ICON                    "small.ico"


/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//
// Menu
//

IDC_WIN32PROJECT1 MENU
BEGIN
    POPUP "&File"
    BEGIN
        MENUITEM "E&xit",                       IDM_EXIT
    END
    POPUP "&Help"
    BEGIN
        MENUITEM "&About ...",                  IDM_ABOUT
    END
END

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//
// Dialog
//

IDD_ABOUTBOX DIALOGEX 0, 0, 170, 62
STYLE DS_SETFONT | DS_MODALFRAME | DS_FIXEDSYS | WS_POPUP | WS_CAPTION | WS_SYSMENU
CAPTION "About Win32Project1"
FONT 8, "MS Shell Dlg", 0, 0, 0x1
BEGIN
    ICON            IDR_MAINFRAME,IDC_STATIC,14,14,21,20
    LTEXT           "Win32Project1, Version 1.0",IDC_STATIC,42,14,114,8,SS_NOPREFIX
    LTEXT           "Copyright (C) 2017",IDC_STATIC,42,26,114,8
    DEFPUSHBUTTON   "OK",IDOK,113,41,50,14,WS_GROUP
END

IDD_DIALOG1 DIALOGEX 0, 0, 309, 176
STYLE DS_SETFONT | DS_MODALFRAME | DS_FIXEDSYS | WS_POPUP | WS_CAPTION | WS_SYSMENU
CAPTION "About Win32Project1"
FONT 8, "MS Shell Dlg", 0, 0, 0x1
BEGIN
    ICON            IDR_MAINFRAME,IDC_STATIC,14,14,21,20
    LTEXT           "Win32Project1, Version 1.0",IDC_STATIC,42,14,114,8,SS_NOPREFIX
    LTEXT           "Copyright (C) 2017",IDC_STATIC,42,26,114,8
    DEFPUSHBUTTON   "OK",IDOK,113,41,50,14,WS_GROUP
END


/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//
// DESIGNINFO
//

#ifdef APSTUDIO_INVOKED
GUIDELINES DESIGNINFO
BEGIN
    IDD_ABOUTBOX, DIALOG
    BEGIN
        LEFTMARGIN, 7
        RIGHTMARGIN, 163
        TOPMARGIN, 7
        BOTTOMMARGIN, 55
    END

    IDD_DIALOG1, DIALOG
    BEGIN
        LEFTMARGIN, 7
        RIGHTMARGIN, 163
        TOPMARGIN, 7
        BOTTOMMARGIN, 55
    END
END
#endif    // APSTUDIO_INVOKED


#ifdef APSTUDIO_INVOKED
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//
// TEXTINCLUDE
//

1 TEXTINCLUDE 
BEGIN
    "resource.h\0"
END

2 TEXTINCLUDE 
BEGIN
    "#ifndef APSTUDIO_INVOKED\r\n"
    "#include ""targetver.h""\r\n"
    "#endif\r\n"
    "#define APSTUDIO_HIDDEN_SYMBOLS\r\n"
    "#include ""windows.h""\r\n"
    "#undef APSTUDIO_HIDDEN_SYMBOLS\r\n"
    "\0"
END

3 TEXTINCLUDE 
BEGIN
    "\r\n"
    "\0"
END

#endif    // APSTUDIO_INVOKED


/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//
// String Table
//

STRINGTABLE
BEGIN
    IDS_APP_TITLE           "Win32Project1"
    IDC_WIN32PROJECT1       "WIN32PROJECT1"
END

#endif    // English (United States) resources
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////



#ifndef APSTUDIO_INVOKED
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//
// Generated from the TEXTINCLUDE 3 resource.
//


/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
#endif    // not APSTUDIO_INVOKED
```

Comment: `IDD_` is the common prefix for dialog IDs, while `IDS_` is used for string resources. You are using `IDD_DIALOG1` in a call to `LoadString`. Is this intentional?

Comment: I merely adopted this from the Visual Studio template. Is there a better way to do this? As I said, if I replace Dialog1 with the autogenerated aboutbox in that line it will open a window. So this is should not be the problem. According to [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648046(v=vs.85).aspx) (see remarks) it looks alright since there is no dedicated function for loading in dialog resources and menus seem to be handled differently altogether.

Comment: `CreateWindow` is the only call you're checking for failure.  There's a good chance that the failure occurred earlier than that.  Add error handling to all the system calls to see where the problem starts.

Comment: GetLastError() tells you why. What is the return value of RegisterClassEx?  Are you triple sure that the string that you pass for the window class name in CreateWindow matches the string for the class name in RegisterClassEx?

Comment: Your question really makes no sense. You've replaced a dialog with what, another dialog? Why are you passing it to LoadString then? There's nowhere in the code you have shown that actually creates a dialog. At least show the .rc script since apparently your question hinges on it.

Comment: Weird. The second call of `LoadStringW()` (needed for `lpszClassName`) seems to fail with this dialog resource. It returns 0. This is very strange, seeing how the method can load the default dialog just fine. It does not load any custom dialog I am trying to add. They are correctly defined in `resource.h` and [resource.rc](https://pastebin.com/5Tpp9kxT). I tried to keep it to a minimal verifiable example. As you can see, both dialogs are exactly the same, safe for size. One can be loaded, the other one can't.

Comment: It is linked in the comment.

Comment: Don't post code in off-site links. Add it to your question. Your problem is you are passing a dialog resource to the LoadString function. This is totally incorrect. If you go back to the original code that VS generates you'll see that it doesn't do this.

Comment: The standard template does just this albeit with a menu and not a dialog. It is also using LoadStringW(). And as explained in that MSDN link earlier, that seems the way to do it. Please correct me if I am wrong, Also if it was totally incorrect, then why is this not an issue with the automatically generated resource? What would be the proper way to load dialogs from the .rc?

Comment: You are wrong. The only resource that LoadString can load is a string. The clue is in the name.

Comment: In the Visual Studio 2015 Win32 application template, the resource file includes a string table entry named `IDC_<projectname>`, corresponding to the name specified in the call to `LoadStringW` that retrieves `szWindowClass`.  Possibly the version of Visual Studio you were using has a slightly different template, but I am confident that you will find that the name specified in the call to `LoadStringW` matches an entry in the string table.  It might *also* match the name of a dialog, menu or other item, but it is the string table entry that is being retrieved.

Comment: 1. Consider yourself corrected: LoadStringW will load strings from the string table.
2. You are misreading the automatically generated code and resource.
3. The proper way to load dialogs is via the `CreateDialog` / `CreateDialogParamEx` etc functions, which DO take a dialog resource name/id.

Comment: Thank you, those explanations helped a lot to fix my issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ERROR_CANNOT_FIND_WND_CLASS means that Windows cannot use the class, most likely because the class does not exist. You never check the return value of `MyRegisterClass`!

It is rare to use `LoadString` to get the class name, most people just put the class name string directly in the code. You never check if LoadString was successful and you cannot load a dialog (IDD_DIALOG1) with LoadString!

You could probably just replace `WCHAR szWindowClass[MAX_LOADSTRING];` with `const WCHAR* L"MyClass";` and it should work. If you still want to load the class name from the resources then you must make sure you are actually loading a valid string.